# Find a string in structured HTML and replace it while maintaining the structure

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following text:

```
...at anyone who did not dress...
```

, where I need to find and replace "did not" with "did't" The task is simple until the text has styles and it becomes:

```
...at anyone who <span style='color: #ff0000;'>did</span>not dress...
```

If I just do

```
obj.innerText.replace("did not", "did't"),
```

then the style will not be saved, and

```
obj.innerHtml.replace("did not", "did't")
```

will not find

Is there an elegant solution?

UDP: there is a position in the text of the beginning and end of a phrase/word, as well as an index in case of repetition

Comment: This could be fairly complex. For instance, would you want to replace `<span>did</span> not`? And should that become `<span>didn't</span>` or `didn't` (without a span element)? I think your question is underspecified in how you need to handle those cases.

Comment: Can you submit the related `<div>` and javascript function?

Comment: If there is an element, I think it could be complex, but the simple idea is you can only check the `not` and replace it into `n't`

Comment: More often that not I solve complex things like this by simplifying everything. For example, if this is in a user input field, then the field should first strip all html tags when content is input. Other than that, my mind goes towards finding the index of the `innerText` then somehow mapping that to the `innerHTML` position, but there will be a million edge cases you'll have to account for

Comment: @Jochem Kuijpers first option

Comment: Do you need a specific solution for one case, e.g. "did not", or do you need a more general solution that search/replaces text in HTML while maintaining structure?

Comment: @JochemKuijpers I need general solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
const html = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
const tags = html.match(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g) || [];
const textTrue = html
    .replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')
    .replace('did not', "didn't");
var lastIndex = 0;
const tagsIndexs = tags.map((item) => {
    lastIndex = html.indexOf(item, lastIndex);
    return lastIndex;
});
const output = tags ? tags.reduce((result, tag, index) => {
    return (
        result.substr(0, tagsIndexs[index]) +
        tag+
        result.substr(tagsIndexs[index])
    );
}, textTrue): textTrue;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p>d<span style="color: #FF0000">id </span>not</p>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: This isn't a great/robust solution, but if it works in your case, I suppose it'll suffice. Here are some ways in which it behaves unexpectedly: `did <br>not` will become `didn<br>'t`, whereas you probably would want `didn't<br>`, and `did not<input>do` will become `didn'td<input>o`, whereas you wouldn't expect it to care about what comes after the replaced part.

Answer (score -1):

if 'not' is not styled(as shown in the example) the best approach I can think of is find all 'did' occurrences and then check if there is 'not' in the neighborhood. If yes remove the 'not' and replace the did with didn't. It is however performance intensive since you can not go for replace, but use indexOf in a while loop and manipulate the html string manually. Additionally if the styling varies(`<span>`,`<b>`,`<i>`..) it will be very difficult(if not impossible) to come with a valid criteria to evaluate the existence of 'not' in the neighborhood of the 'did'. The same approach can be used on 'not' instead of did, but again it really depends on the styling you need to preserve.

Comment: The text-content is linear, it's definitely not impossible to do this correctly. You just have to, like you said, traverse the HTML elements and search for matching cases manually.

Comment: the tricky part comes when the cases are too many, in order for a replace to work reliably you need a valid criteria, to ensure that you are in the right case. You can and will have 'not' without a 'did' and vice versa, also, both keywords can appear as partial matches. You can not add spaces in the search criteria, because of the styling, if it is only spans you can come with a fixed condition to check, but if the html tags vary(something on which the OP is unclear) you will end up stacking contradicting conditions. It is a disaster case in text processing- too many variables, no clear test